# jQuery equality statement not functioning correctly

Tags: jquery

I have written a small jQuery script that checks the computed size of a div, sets the css height of this div to that height, then uses this height to calculate whether to initiate an animation or not. 
The have printed out the variables to check that they are the same and it seems they are but it never seems to run through the 'if' even when they are the same. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?
The main aim of this code is to hide an absolutely-positioned div off of the screen, then when an anchor is clicked the script is run and the div will slide in or out accordingly.
Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var outerdivheight = $('.login_wrap').outerHeight();
                divheight = 0 - outerdivheight;
                $('.login_wrap').css("top", divheight + "px");
                $('#login_tab').click(function(){   

                if (parseInt($('.login_wrap').css('top') == outerdivheight)) { marg = '0'; } else { marg = divheight; }
                    $('.login_wrap').stop().animate({'top':marg}, 'slow');
                });
            });
```

Comment: look at the brackets for `parseInt()`

Comment: A general tip.  If you are using a very highly used library/framework and are about to say "this massively used function in a major library doesn't work" - the odds are exceptionally in favour of incorrect use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some parentheses in the wrong place:

Try `(parseInt($('.login_wrap').css('top')) == outerdivheight)`

Comment: and get rid of the one at the end of the `if` block - `});` should be `}`

Comment: That's the end of the `click` handler function, the `if` statement is all on one line :)

Comment: Ha thankyou! I knew it would of been something stupid.. apologies it's Friday afternoon here and I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

```
if  (parseInt($('.login_wrap').css('top')) == outerdivheight)   {


     }
```

what you had was :

```
   if (parseInt($('.login_wrap').css('top') == outerdivheight))
```

you tried to do parseInt on the boolean that is returned from comparing